# Qt: Window size execution methods?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtgui

When trying to set a fixed window size why doesn't the following code work:

```
window->setSizeIncrement(1024,600);
window->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

But this code does:

```
window->setMaximumHeight(600);
window->setMinimumHeight(600);
window->setMaximumWidth(1024);
window->setMinimumWidth(1024);
```

I achieve what I want, a fixed width and height window.  Not as efficiently as I had thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [`setFixedSize(const QSize & s)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize) to achieve the same.

As for the `setsizeIncrement()`, as discussed in [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#sizeIncrement-prop) it merely sets an increment step for the window size. What's more, depending on your platform the following might be important:

> Warning: The size increment has no effect under Windows, and may be
>   disregarded by the window manager on X11.

Comment: Your genius! Even better and it works!  Good to know facts also.